# Depth-first search implementation for node/tasks ordering

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph-algorithm, topological-sort

The question is as follows and its details can be found [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-the-ordering-of-tasks-from-given-dependencies/):

> There are a total of n tasks you have to pick, labeled from 0 to n-1.
> Some tasks may have prerequisites tasks, for example to pick task 0
> you have to first finish tasks 1, which is expressed as a pair: [0, 1]
>
> Given the total number of tasks and a list of prerequisite pairs,
> return the ordering of tasks you should pick to finish all tasks.

One of the solutions given on the page utilizes DFS-based implementation of topological sort.

```
vector<unordered_set<int> > make_graph(int numTasks, 
             vector<pair<int, int> >& prerequisites) 
{ 
    vector<unordered_set<int> > graph(numTasks); 
    for (auto pre : prerequisites) 
        graph[pre.second].insert(pre.first); 
    return graph; 
} 
  
bool dfs(vector<unordered_set<int> >& graph, int node,  
           vector<bool>& onpath, vector<bool>& visited,  
                                vector<int>& toposort) 
{ 
    if (visited[node]) 
        return false; 
    onpath[node] = visited[node] = true; 
    for (int neigh : graph[node]) 
        if (onpath[neigh] || dfs(graph, neigh, onpath, visited, toposort)) 
            return true; 
    toposort.push_back(node); 
    return onpath[node] = false; 
} 
  
vector<int> findOrder(int numTasks, vector<pair<int, int> >& prerequisites) 
{ 
    vector<unordered_set<int> > graph = make_graph(numTasks, prerequisites); 
    vector<int> toposort; 
    vector<bool> onpath(numTasks, false), visited(numTasks, false); 
    for (int i = 0; i < numTasks; i++) 
        if (!visited[i] && dfs(graph, i, onpath, visited, toposort)) 
            return {}; 
    reverse(toposort.begin(), toposort.end()); 
    return toposort; 
} 
  
int main() 
{ 
    int numTasks = 4; 
    vector<pair<int, int> > prerequisites; 
  
    prerequisites.push_back(make_pair(1, 0)); 
    prerequisites.push_back(make_pair(2, 1)); 
    prerequisites.push_back(make_pair(3, 2)); 
    vector<int> v = findOrder(numTasks, prerequisites); 
  
    for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++) { 
        cout << v[i] << " "; 
    } 
  
    return 0; 
}
```

I am particularly confused about the role of the `vector<bool> onpath(numTasks, false)` in this code.

```
vector<int> findOrder(int numTasks, vector<pair<int, int> >& prerequisites) 
{ 
    vector<unordered_set<int> > graph = make_graph(numTasks, prerequisites); 
    vector<int> toposort; 
    vector<bool> onpath(numTasks, false), visited(numTasks, false); 
    for (int i = 0; i < numTasks; i++) 
        if (!visited[i] && dfs(graph, i, onpath, visited, toposort)) 
            return {}; 
    reverse(toposort.begin(), toposort.end()); 
    return toposort; 
}
```

The boolean function `dfs` only returns true when an element in the `onpath` vector is true.

```
bool dfs(vector<unordered_set<int> >& graph, int node,  
           vector<bool>& onpath, vector<bool>& visited,  
                                vector<int>& toposort) 
{ 
    if (visited[node]) 
        return false; 
    onpath[node] = visited[node] = true; 
    for (int neigh : graph[node]) 
        if (onpath[neigh] || dfs(graph, neigh, onpath, visited, toposort)) 
            return true; 
    toposort.push_back(node); 
    return onpath[node] = false; 
}
```

**What purpose does the `onpath` vector actually serve in the solution?** I know the input of a topological sort algorithm must be a Directed Acyclic Graph and if the algorithm encounters any loop or cycle in the graph/input, the algorithm terminates. Is this what the `onpath` vector is for?

If the purpose of the `onpath` vector is really that, then what purpose does this line serve:

```
if (!visited[i] && dfs(graph, i, onpath, visited, toposort)) 
    return {};
```

Apparently, `dfs` only returns true when an element in `onpath` is true. It makes sense that an empty array should be returned if that happens. What is the necessity of checking dfs results with the `visited` array?

Comment: Yes, the purpose of `onpath` is to prevent looping during a search. The purpose of `visited` is to prevent **starting** a search on a node that has already been searched.

Comment: @john Thank you for the response. If the purpose of `visited` is to prevent starting a search on a visited node, then wouldn't OR be a better condition than AND?

Comment: After looking at the code more closely, I saw that an element is being set from `false` to `true` in both the `visited` and `onpath` vectors at the SAME TIME. Moreover, it seems like `dfs` returns true when the `onpath` element is true.

Comment: The condition checks for a condition that is unlikely to occur: is the element set to `true` in the `onpath` vector but to `false` in the `visited` vector? This is because the status of the element in both vectors is being changed at the same time.